How to refresh a query in VBA when the query name is the result of a concatenated string
I'm trying to use
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Dim WeekNum As String
Dim QueryName As Variant

WeekNum = WorksheetFunction.WeekNum(Now, vbSunday)
QueryName = ("2024Week" & WeekNum)
ActiveWorkbook.Queries("QueryName").Refresh
End Sub

Essentially I want the apporiate query to refresh based on the name of the query containing the same weeknumber as the current week of the year.  I cannot seem to find any information about this.
Here is the error I receive:

Run-time error Cannot find a query by the name 'QueryName'


no need for the "'s

Remove the quotes and moop through the existing connections to find the query that matches the name you are providing :
   Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim WeekNum As String
    Dim QueryName As String
    Dim conn As WorkbookConnection

    WeekNum = WorksheetFunction.WeekNum(Now, vbSunday)
    QueryName = "2024Week" & WeekNum

    For Each conn In ActiveWorkbook.Connections
        If conn.Name = QueryName Then
            conn.Refresh
            Exit For
        End If
    Next conn
End Sub


That throws a different run-time error "Object doesn't support this method or property"

Maybe you need to loop through connections to find the query that matches the name you want

Add code to validate the existence of the query.
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim WeekNum As String
    Dim QueryName As String
    Dim objQuery As Object
    WeekNum = WorksheetFunction.WeekNum(Now, vbSunday)
    QueryName = "2024Week" & WeekNum
    On Error Resume Next
    Set objQuery = ActiveWorkbook.Queries(QueryName)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If objQuery Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "The query [" & QueryName & "] does not exist."
    Else
        objQuery.Refresh
    End If
End Sub

